# Проблема с фильтрацией в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var human = document.getElementById("human");
var ul = document.getElementById('menuUL');
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
var a;

human.onkeyup = function() {
 var filter = human.value;
 for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
  if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
   li[i].style.display = '';
  }
  else {
   li[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
 }

}
```

```html
<div id="sorting">
 <input type="text" id="human" placeholder="Имя">
 <ul id="menuUL">
  <li class="header">A</li>
  <li><a href="#">Aндрей</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Алексей</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Альдус</a></li>
  <li class="header">Б</li>
  <li><a href="#">Бахангин</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Борис</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Братислав</a></li>
  <li class="header">В</li>
  <li><a href="#">Валентин</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Володимир</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Вадим</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

При вводе в input текст для фильтрации выводиться ошибка

Comment: в чем вопрос то?...опишите словами с чем возникла проблема...а то так сразу не очень понятно

Comment: При вводе текста в input выводятся ошибки.

Comment: @Termoxin, у вас же видно, что некий элемент undefined. Есть проблема задебажить и посмотреть почему?

Comment: сейчас ответ напишу, ошибка там очевидная

Answer (score 4):

Вот, исправил ваш код, вроде всё работает.

**UPD:** плюс я исправил ещё ваши косяки :


`var filter = human.value.toUpperCase();`

Нужно было так создать `filter`, что бы поиск работал правильней.


А сама ошибка, нужно было добавить `if`

```
if(a){
...Ваш код..
}
```

```js
human.onkeyup = function() {
var human = document.getElementById("human");
var ul = document.getElementById('menuUL');
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
var a;
var filter = human.value.toUpperCase();
 for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if(a){
   if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    li[i].style.display = "";
   }
      else {
    li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
        }
 }

}
```

```html
<div id="sorting">
 <input type="text" id="human" placeholder="Имя">
 <ul id="menuUL">
  <li class="header">A</li>
  <li><a href="#">Aндрей</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Алексей</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Альдус</a></li>
  <li class="header">Б</li>
  <li><a href="#">Бахангин</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Борис</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Братислав</a></li>
  <li class="header">В</li>
  <li><a href="#">Валентин</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Володимир</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Вадим</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

разберем текскт ошибки:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 38,
  "colno": 7
}
```

В тексте ошибки нам говорится, что мы не можем обратиться к свойству `innerHTML` на неопределенном объекте(другими словами данного объекта не существует).

и даже указана строка, в которой произошла ошибка

```
    if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
```

соответственно, в каком-то случае `a` у нас может быть неопределенно.

Для начала ответим на вопрос: что такое `a`

```
a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

`a` - это ссылка внутри тега `<li>`

проблема в том, что НЕ В КАЖДОМ `<li>...</li>` есть ссылка

например

```
<li class="header">Б</li>
```

Соответственно,когда вы пытаетесь обратиться к ссылке внутри данного пункта списка, происходит ошибка, т.к. вы пытаетесь обратиться к объекту которого нет.

**Что делать?**

ответ простой:

поставить проверку перед тем как обращаться к данной переменной:

```
if (typeof a != 'undefined'){
   //...
}
```

В Вашем случае удобнее будет использовать условие от противного и наоборот пропустить даную итерацию цикла, если данный элемент неопределен: то есть:

```
    if(typeof a == 'undefined')
       continue;
```

И как справедливо заметил *Alisher Yerkimbekov*, у Вас недочёт в строке:

```
var filter = human.value;
```

Ошибка в том, что текст ссылок при проверке у Вас приводится к верхнему регистру, в то время как текст, который вы вводите остаётся без изменений. Для корректного поиска его стоит тоже привести к верхнему регистру

```
var filter = human.value.toUpperCase();
```

---

**В ИТОГЕ:**

```js
var human = document.getElementById("human");
var ul = document.getElementById('menuUL');
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
var a;

human.onkeyup = function() {
 var filter = human.value.toUpperCase();
 for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
  if(typeof a == 'undefined')
      continue;
  if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
   li[i].style.display = '';
  }
  else {
   li[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
 }

}
```

```html
<div id="sorting">
 <input type="text" id="human" placeholder="Имя">
 <ul id="menuUL">
  <li class="header">A</li>
  <li><a href="#">Aндрей</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Алексей</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Альдус</a></li>
  <li class="header">Б</li>
  <li><a href="#">Бахангин</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Борис</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Братислав</a></li>
  <li class="header">В</li>
  <li><a href="#">Валентин</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Володимир</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Вадим</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```